# Bluetooth communication from PC to mobile phone, use laptop speaker and mic during voice call

Tags: c#, audio, bluetooth, stream, 32feet

I am using 32feet.net library for connecting with Bluetooth mobile phone.
I have successfully discovered devices, successfully paired with device.
I have successfully made a call using AT command with the help of 
[Bluetooth dial with 32feet.net and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960208/bluetooth-dial-with-32feet-net-and-c-sharp)

I want to use the speaker and mic of laptop during the voice call going on the mobile phone.

My C# code for dialing a call is

```
BluetoothEndPoint bep = new BluetoothEndPoint(phone.DeviceAddress,BluetoothService.Handsfree);

cli = new BluetoothClient();

cli.Connect(bep);
peerStream = cli.GetStream();
peerStream = Listofdevices.cli.GetStream();
String dialCmd4 = "ATD"+txtdialer.Text+";\r\n";
Byte[] dcB = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dialCmd4);
Listofdevices.peerStream.Write(dcB, 0, dcB.Length);

Byte[] sRes = new Byte[200];
peerStream.Read(sRes, 0, 199);
```

How can I use my speaker and mic of laptop for communication on the call?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?