# How to set an incoming phone call listener in c# application with phone connected to pc via bluetooth?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, 32feet

I am using 32feet.net library to achieve bluetooth connectivity of my c# application to a mobile phone. Up until now i have achieved Discovery, Pairing, and Dialing a phone call. Dialing is being done by using AT command to the phone.

Some useful links about above mentioned activities are

[Pair bluetooth devices to a computer with 32feet .NET Bluetooth library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802791/pair-bluetooth-devices-to-a-computer-with-32feet-net-bluetooth-library)

[Bluetooth dial with 32feet.net and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960208/bluetooth-dial-with-32feet-net-and-c-sharp)

I am looking for help in receiving incoming phone call through my application.
Now from different forums all i have come to know that we can accept an incoming phone call by using "ATA" command.

https://burakalakusen.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/to-control-your-mobile-phone-by-at-commands-via-bluetooth/

An incoming call will send a "RING" notification to the application, but i dont know how to be able to read the RING notification or make my phone send a RING Notification to my application.

Appreciate your help.